# Prop TypeScript Error With React Component, Using Styled-Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, variables, styled-components

I'm creating a Link component that has an option to change color to gray, using the `disabled` prop. When I hover over `{({ disabled }`, TypeScript is giving me a `Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>` error.

Syntax looks correct, not sure what I'm missing here.

```
const StyledLink = styled.a`

  color: blue;

  ${({ disabled }) => 
    disabled &&
    css`
      color: gray;
    `}
`;


export type TextLinkProps = {
  /**
   * text to be passed in as a link
   */
  link: string;
  /**
   * text to be rendered in the component.
   */
  children: React.ReactNode;
  /**
   * If `true`, color will be gray.
   */
  disabled?: boolean;
};

export function TextLink({ children, link, disabled = false }: TextLinkProps) {
  return (
    <StyledLink href={link} disabled={disabled}> 
      {children}
    </StyledLink>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the props types you get in your styled component, as such:

```js
const StyledLink = styled.a<{ disabled?: boolean }>``
```

Also just noticed, you can simplify you styles to omit `css`:

```js
${({ disabled }) => disabled && "color: gray"};
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is right: anchor elements don't have attribute `disabled`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: He still might want to use that as a custom prop for styling based on the given condition